# Error trying to fetch post from blog to flutter mobile application

Tags: flutter, wordpress-rest-api

I am working on a news app for my blog. The baseUrl has an issue and when I run, I get this error.

```
     Exception has occurred.

     WordPressError (WordPress Error! 
                code: null, 
                message: {“code”:“rest_user_cannot_view”,
                          “message”:“Sorry, you are not allowed to list users.”,
                          “data”:{“status”:401}}, 
                status: null)
```

Comment: Exception has occurred.
WordPressError (WordPress Error! code: null, message: <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: <div class="wp-die-message"><p>There has been a critical error on your website.</p><p><a href="https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Learn more about debugging in WordPress.</a></p></div></body>
</html>
 , status: null)

Comment: please edit these into your post

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an unauthorized area. This is about privileges. You can read more about the [HTTP status codes](https://httpstatuses.com/401#:%7E:text=The%20request%20has%20not%20been,applicable%20to%20the%20target%20resource.).

Comment: I have JWT Authentication for WP REST API set

Answer (score 0):

suPHP_ConfigPath /home/USER/public_html

Adding these in .htaccess solved the issue [process](https://hoststud.com/resources/using-suphp_configpath-in-htaccess-and-php-ini-files.298/)